# Pseudo-code for rules of probability?

Tags: programming, probability-or-statistics

I am having a hard time in Stats understanding some basic rules of probability and set-theory, namely $P(A|B)$, $P(A\ \textrm{and}\ B)$ and $P(A\ \textrm{or}\ B)$ where $A$ and $B$ depend on each other. I use *Mathematica* all the time through my school, and I love to program in my free-time (sometimes writing small scripts for *Mathematica*).

I can understand confusing subjects that deal with logic when they are in a programming language syntax, so I thought I could understand what's going on better if I had a written syntax to look at. Will anyone bother to help?

Comment: Are you asking for an example on how to deal with Bayes theorem in Mathematica?

Comment: @Stefan In a way, yes. Basically, what would the code for those three basic rules look like in Mathematica's programming language so that I can play around with it to understand it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wolfram Demonstration Project has 13 submissions that use Bayes Theorem:
See [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=bayes)

[image]

More specifically:

[Probability Of Being Sick After Having Tested Positive For A Disease](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ProbabilityOfBeingSickAfterHavingTestedPositiveForADiseaseBa/)

[Bayes's Theorem And Inverse Probability](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BayessTheoremAndInverseProbability/)

[Total Probability And Bayes's Theorem](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TotalProbabilityAndBayessTheorem/)

All of these will have downloadable code to help you learn this.

Good luck.